# 3D internal subregion

Tags: differential-equations, regions, mesh, finite-element-method

I'm trying to follow the documentation for [Element Mesh Generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html), but somehow I cannot understand it correctly. Here is a simplified version of my real problem.
I'm trying to simulate the temperature distribution in a pipeline. In the pipeline, there should be a fluid (fluid flow) and a solid domain (pipe wall). These 2 domains have different equations and should be connected with each other with `NeumannValue`.

E.g. I'd like to have something like this

[image: pipe]

```
wall[x_, y_, z_] := ((0.9/10)^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.1^2) && 0 <= z <= 1
fluid[x_,y_,z_] := x^2 + y^2 < (0.9/10)^2 && 0 <= z <= 1
```

RegionUnion doesn't give me what I want, because the internal boundary would disappear. Does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT:**

here is something I tried

1. I thought to build a solid region and a fluid region, retrieve their
   boundary elements and coordinates and use `ToBoundaryMesh` could
   work, but it didn't.

000

```
\[CapitalOmega]1 = ImplicitRegion[wall[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

With[{mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]1]},co1 = mesh["Coordinates"]; be1 = mesh["BoundaryElements"];]

\[CapitalOmega]2 = ImplicitRegion[fluid[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

With[{mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]2]},
co2 = mesh["Coordinates"];
be2 = mesh["BoundaryElements"];]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[co1, co2], "BoundaryElements" -> Join[be1, be2]]

ToBoundaryMesh::fememib: The input has or generated an intersecting boundary and cannot be processed.
```

2. I thought I could treat the fluid domain as a `RegionHole`, but it also didn't work.
   [image: mesh]

Obviously, it only contains the pipe wall not the fluid.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ImplicitRegion[wall[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]]
ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None]["Wireframe"]
```

**Update**

@user21's solution somehow fails in the other situations. E.g.

```
L = 0.5; 
hi = 2/3 1.25; 
ri = 0.01; 
m = ToElementMesh[
      ImplicitRegion[-L/2 <= x <= L/2 && 
        0 <= y <= 1.25 && ! (x^2 + (y - hi)^2 < ri^2), {x, y}], 
      "RegionHoles" -> None(*,"RegionMarker"\[Rule]{{{0,hi},1,10},{{0,
      1.25/3},2,0.1}},*), "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]
m["Wireframe"]
coords = m["Coordinates"];
c1 = Join[coords, ConstantArray[{0.}, {Length[coords]}], 2];
c2 = Join[coords, ConstantArray[{1.}, {Length[coords]}], 2];
ele = m["MeshElements"];
max = Max[ElementIncidents[ele]]
tohigherIndex[type_[inci_, marker___], max_] := 
 type[inci + max, marker]
tmpBM = ToBoundaryMesh[m];
sides = QuadElement[Map[Join[#1, Reverse[#1 + max]] &, #]] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[
    Flatten[MeshElementSplitByMarker[tmpBM["BoundaryElements"]]]];
bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[c1, c2], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> 
   Join[ele, tohigherIndex[#, max] & /@ ele, sides]]
bm["Wireframe"]
```

The code above gives me the following error

```
TriangleElement::femdmi: Mesh element type TriangleElement does not match incidents {}.
ToBoundaryMesh::fembdel: TriangleElement[{{60,96,95},{19,95,96},{60,59,9},{95,59,60},{19,11,635},{1182,10,67},{10,1182,11},{1182,67,79},{95,635,79},{635,95,19},{79,635,1182},{1182,635,11}}] is not a valid mesh element. Possible causes are that the mesh element type is not valid, not enough coordinates have been specified, or that incidents have values less than or equal to zero.
```

Is there any solution that can be generalized to random geometry?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I added the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: I have updated the code a bit to work in other cases as well.

Yes, this is too difficult. Here is a workaround for this case. It's not trivial but it works well for the problem at hand. Basically, we generate a boundary mesh from a 2D mesh that has an interior region:

```
m = ToElementMesh[Annulus[{0, 0}, {9/10, 1}], "RegionHoles" -> None, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity];
m["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Next, we extract the coordinates and get the largest incident number.

```
coords = m["Coordinates"];
c1 = Join[coords, ConstantArray[{0.}, {Length[coords]}], 2];
c2 = Join[coords, ConstantArray[{1.}, {Length[coords]}], 2];
ele = m["MeshElements"];
max = Max[ElementIncidents[ele]]
136
```

We extract the boundary elements from the mesh and construct the sides:

```
tohigherIndex[type_[inci_, marker___], max_] := 
 type[inci + max, marker]
(* old code: not good *)
(* tmpBM = ToBoundaryMesh[m];
sides = QuadElement[Map[Join[#1, Reverse[#1 + max]] &, #]] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[
    Flatten[MeshElementSplitByMarker[tmpBM["BoundaryElements"]]]];*)
sides = QuadElement[Map[Join[#1, Reverse[#1 + max]] &, #]] & /@ 
   ElementIncidents[
    Flatten[MeshElementSplitByMarker[m["BoundaryElements"]]]];
```

We now construct the boundary mesh:

```
bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[c1, c2], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> 
   Join[ele, tohigherIndex[#, max] & /@ ele, sides]]

bm["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

And generate the full mesh:

```
ToElementMesh[bm]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

With the updated version I get this for your second mesh:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to generalize the procedure? I'm encountering a similar situation now and your technique doesn't work any more.

Comment: @407Peezy Try the updated code and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it helps to have different `"RegionMarker"` for different domains? I am not sure if this is useful for OP original problem regarding boundary conditions, but I would like to show another approach to generating such FEM mesh.

Since the geometry of this pipe is quite simple we can mesh it with structured quadrilaterals. This also gives you a lot more control over element size and distribution. I have been developing a package [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) to help with this.

Load the package after installing it and define geometry parameters.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
center = {0, 0};
r1 = 0.9; (* inner radius *)
r2 = 1.; (* outer radius *)
n = 10; (* number of elements on quarter of disk perimeter *)
length = 4; (* length of cylinder *)
n2 = 10; (* number of elements in length direction *)
```

Create structured mesh on `Disk`. This represents the "fluid" domain.

```
diskMesh = DiskMesh[center, r1, n]
(* ElementMesh[{{-0.9, 0.9}, {-0.9, 0.9}}, QuadElement["<" 220 ">"]}] *)
```

Create structured mesh on `Annulus`, which represents the "solid" domain. Element spacing on the edge should match the one of `diskMesh`.

```
annulusMesh = AnnulusMesh[center, {r1, r2}, {4*n, 2}]
(* ElementMesh[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, {QuadElement["<" 80 ">"]}] *)
```

Observe the result for both meshes (they are still two different `ElementMesh` objects).

```
Show[
  diskMesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@Yellow]],
  annulusMesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@Orange]]
]
```

[image: mesh2D]

And then the crucial step. Extrude quadrialteral meshes in Z direction, add "RegionMarker" of your choice and merge meshes into one `ElementMesh` object.

```
mesh3D = MergeMesh[{
   AddMeshMarkers[ExtrudeMesh[diskMesh, length, n2],"MeshElementsMarker" -> 1],
   AddMeshMarkers[ExtrudeMesh[annulusMesh, length, n2],"MeshElementsMarker" -> 2]
}]

mesh3D["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements",
  "MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ {Yellow, Orange},
  Axes -> True
]]
```

[image: mesh3D]

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find a dirty solution on my own. If the fluid part is removed completely like what I did in the second try, Mathematica will not consider it as a RegionHole. Thus, the idea is not to remove it completely. Somehow this dirty solution works with the equations too.

```
wholeRegion[x_, y_, z_] := (x^2 + y^2 <= 0.1^2) && 0 <= z <= 1
fluid[x_,y_,z_] := x^2 + y^2 < (0.9/10)^2 && 0.01 <= z <= 0.99
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  ImplicitRegion[wholeRegion[x, y, z] && ! fluid[x, y, z], {x, y, z}],
   "RegionHoles" -> {0, 0, 0.5}, 
  "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 10^(-4)]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None(*,
  MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]10^-5*)]
```

[image]

But still, I hope that Wolfram could optimize the RegionHole to make generating the 3D internal subregion easier.