# Converting .stl files to meshes for FEA

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I'm trying to conduct finite element analysis on imported .stl models from SketchUp. I can't seem to generate an ElementMesh. I think it may be something to do with intersecting boundaries, and this question asked here ([3D internal subregion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172500/3d-internal-)\
subregion) is perhaps relevant. Does anyone have any good methods of importing models into Mathematica, and then turning them into meshes?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nd7e81g4qu9ddv0/plank1.stl?dl=0

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
model = Import[plank1.stl"];  (*plank1.stl in linked dropbox file*)
repairModel = RepairMesh[model]; 
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[repairModel];

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]
```

Comment: Have a look at the output of `FindMeshDefects[model]` perhaps that gives a clue what needs to be done to clean this up.

Comment: It appears that there are a number of 'overlapping faces'. Is there a way to mend this?